# Class Method Implementation in Header

Tags: objective-c

In Objective-C, if I have a class that contains only class methods (no member variables or instance methods) can I define class methods in the class's header file (.h), and skip creating a .m file?

Comment: isn't a "best practice" but why don't try it?

Comment: You can, but you better not. Objective-C ain't C++ (fortunately).

Comment: Well, is their side-effects to doing so? Does it break Xcode's method recognition, is it ARC friendly, is it a hack? Has Apple said anything about it?

Comment: Then what is the meaning of separating interface and implementation? You never give your implementation file with your framework.

Comment: The class in question merely contains a few helper methods that, technically, could be written as (lengthily) preprocessor macros, but I'd rather avoid those.

Comment: @matheszabi so what if it compiles and runs? what if implementations in the header are implied to be inlined, or what if the next release of Xcode breaks support for this?

Comment: @Mr.Smith just create an Util.h and .m and implements your methods in m. You wana scroll 3000 lines in your .h to see wahrt functions are there?! not a great idea!

Comment: you are prone to get duplicate symbols if you start implementing stuff in the headers

Comment: I did a bit of snooping into cocoa's header files to see if Apple does this at all, but I didn't find any occurrences. It seems unlikely I'd find it too, since it would show Apple's coding of that method.

Comment: I like the question. Why we need so many comments of "just do it and don't ask" is beyond me. You may as well quote from the bible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can*, but you basically shouldn't.  While you can put your @implementation in a header, it's counter-convention and it may have unintended side-effects, the same as in C++ or other languages (e.g. you can't control what will have been #included before your header was #include, so you can't be sure you have a sane global namespace).

The best practices in Objective-C are to keep only declarations in header files, along with documentation.  Since the documentation is generally quite verbose (if written well) that's already a fair bit of content in your header - adding code on top of that would be too much.

Keep in mind also that there's no inlining of Objective-C methods, whether class or instance.  That's one of the big reasons putting code in header files is a relatively popular practice in C/C++.  You can of course put static functions in your Objective-C header file, so you could implement your code that way, but that may be an undesirable design - for example, class methods provide a form of namespacing which is generally wise to take advantage of.